# What is the optimal strategy for the army battles?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

I mostly just hold down spacebar and all out attack while trying to match the 3 color system during the army battles. There must be some other tactic that I'm not aware of, yes?

Should I be using special attacks often? They seem to be draining my army points which doesn't allow me to resupply my army towards the end of the battle.

Should I be overtaking the structures? They are costing me army points and I don't even know how beneficial they are to the overall battle.

Comment: The battle system is pretty poor in my opinion, the best tactic seems to be just try and be over-levelled, or do kingdom research to boost battle related skills. There are little tactics involved other that the colour system, and even that seems hit and miss. They could have done a much better job in my opinion